# Location of a sound file used by gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio

I am tinkering around with the gem for ruby on rails, upon an executable I want to play a sound from a wave file, but it seem not to work as I thought, ones the gem is installed... 
So far I have

```
cmd = ("afplay 'sound/activated.wav'")
exec cmd
```

with the file located und lib/sound/activate.wav, within my gem folder, but if I use my gem it can't find the file...
Is there a particular location i have to store files?
thanks

Comment: worth mentioning that the code posted is located in my ruby file within the lib folder so the mygem.rb and sound folder are both on the same level in the lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run that, `afplay` will be looking at `sound/activated.wav` from the current directory, not from the gem directory.

In Ruby 2.x you can find the directory where your script is located in `__dir__`. So (with all the precautions taken):

```
require 'shellwords'
file = File.join(__dir__, 'sound', 'activated.wav')
escfile = Shellwords.escape(file)
cmd = "afplay #{escfile}"
```

If you need to make it compatible with older Rubies, `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))` is the same thing as `__dir__`.

Note that `exec` will *replace* your `ruby` process with the new `afplay` process, which will obviously terminate your Ruby code. In most cases you would rather want `system`.

Comment: is there a comand like afplay for linux OS (or even for windows) as well?

Comment: @Yogi: [Windows](http://superuser.com/a/528541/39723), [Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/276596/play-mp3-or-wav-file-via-linux-command-line).